# Random Data listing without repeating records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

Its been 5 hours has passed and i'm still trying to list my data's as a random to my page.
I've checked many samples. Here's what i've tried before i write down.

db schema

```
--tblquestions--
id(int)
Question(varchar)
GroupId(int)

--tblhints--
id(int)
hint(varchar)
pic(varchar)
GroupId(int)
```

**tblquestions.GroupId = tblhints.GroupId**

In **`tblquestions.Question`** field, there is two values for each record. For example:

```
id(1) Question(America) GroupId(5)
id(2) Question(Germany) GroupId(5)

id(3) Question(Italy) GroupId(6)
id(4) Question(Ukraine) GroupId(6)
```

Like this.

**This is a poll app**

I'm giving a hint and picture to users and there is two options(tblquestions.Question).
users choosing one and questions are continious until to the end.

And it has to be loaded randomly.

I've tried **`order by`** , **`group by`** and many possibilies. 
nothing.

Its listing randomly but there is always duplicated records in my page.

Tried examples :

```
<?php
$sorusayisi = 57;
for ($i=1; $i < $sorusayisi ; $i++) { 

            // $soruId = array();
            $soruQues = array();
            $soruCevapId = array();

            $sqlSorular=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblquestions AS r1 
                JOIN (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tblquestions)) AS id) AS r2 
                    WHERE r1.Id >= r2.Id");

            while($rsSorular = mysql_fetch_array($sqlSorular)) {

                $soruCevapId[] = $rsSorular["Id"];
                $soruQues[] = $rsSorular["Question"];
                $soruGrId = intval($rsSorular["GroupId"]);

            }

            $sHint = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblhints WHERE GroupId=".$soruGrId."");
            $rsHint = mysql_fetch_array($sHint);
                $soruHint = $rsHint["hint"];
                $soruPic = $rsHint["pic"];

            $sCevap = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblanswers WHERE GroupId=".$soruGrId."");
            $rsCevap = mysql_fetch_array($sCevap);
                $cevapId = $rsCevap["Answer"];
                // $soruPic = $rsCevap["pic"];


?>
//div codes

<?php

}>
```

---

```
 for ($i=1; $i < $kac_soru_sorulacak ; $i++) { 

             $soruCevapId = array();
             $question = array();


         $hintsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblhints GROUP BY GroupId ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
         $hintrs = mysql_fetch_assoc($hintsql);
         // $sorular = array();      
         $hintId = intval($hintrs["id"]);
         $hint = $hintrs["hint"];
         $foto = $hintrs["pic"];

         $grupid = intval($hintrs["GroupId"]);
         ################

         ################
         $cevapsql = mysql_query("select * from tblanswers where GroupId=".$grupid."");
         $cevaprs = mysql_fetch_assoc($cevapsql);
         $cevapId = intval($cevaprs["Answer"]);
         ################

         ################
         $hintsayi =  mysql_num_rows($hintsql);
         $siksql = mysql_query("select * from tblquestions where GroupId=".$grupid." order by rand()");

            while ($sikrs=mysql_fetch_assoc($siksql)) {
                $question[] =$sikrs["Question"];
                $soruCevapId[] = $sikrs["Id"];
            } 

         ################

    ?>
```

Would you please show me some code example?

Many Thanks

Comment: How about [shuffling](http://php.net/shuffle) in PHP?

Comment: So, the problem is: "there is always duplicated records in my page". One solves this in SQL with "[distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)". Then you randomize the order. You might want to work through http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html

Comment: how about SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT number_of_items_youwant

Comment: @Farce yes i've tried shuffle it works in numbers but i couln't execute it in arrays. :/

Comment: @GitaarLAB some people says that you can try sessions. but i don't know how i can do it and how it works? any idea?

Comment: @SamD distinct doesn't work for me because i don't have double records. i have grouped records.

Comment: what do sessions have to do (solve) with duplicate records?

Comment: @GitaarLAB like 
if(!$_SESSION['quiz']) { $_SESSION['quiz'] = array(); }
$_SESSION['quiz'][] = $row['id'];
for execute : 
$session = implode(", ", $_SESSION['quiz']);
$query = "select * from quiz WHRE `id` NOT IN (".$session.") order by rand() LIMIT 1";

Comment: but i couldn't figure it out..i'm totally confused. i've tried many samples. now i can't see which one is true :)

Comment: (I'm still confused about what you are trying to accomplish): Is the problem that users get duplicate questions (questions they've answered before), in other words: tracking what questions the user already answered?

Comment: @GitaarLAB .. In short: There is a picture(country),hint and two options. Users trying to make a guess to find which country is it. There is tblquestions and tblhint table. Country names in tblquestions with groupId(i explained it up there).. when i use 'for', it duplicate records i mean it shows 3 questions in one page load. there is 50query. I'm passing something but i can't find it. I hope its more clear now.

Comment: well, the session-thing looks to me as a way to track what questions the user already answered, so I don't fully understand how that relates to 3 questions showing in one page load. I now also wonder what you are passing that you can't find.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables aren't too big, you could create the field rdm_order (type: FLOAT) with a random number and sort by it. As I said, might be too expensive if your table is too big, but on the other hand, it's a very fast and easy solution:

```
UPDATE tblquestions SET rdm_order=RAND();
SELECT * FROM tblquestions WHERE GroupId={$grupid} ORDER BY rdm_order;
```

You could also run the UPDATE only once per user session, though.

Comment: Does that mean you'd dynamically create a new table with questions per user?

Comment: No, you just update the rdm_order field before doing the SELECT. Or you define a pattern when you want to update tblquestions.rdm_order

Comment: Another solution would be to fetch everything and then randomize your results (array): http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php#99624

Comment: @ClaudioBredfeldt thanks but this is not what i'm looking for. and i've tried shuffle as well. nothing has changed :/

Comment: Are there precautions to take (like locking the table for a single user while making both sql-statements) in a concurrent multi-user environment?

Comment: @GitaarLAB yes, you'll lock the table during the UPDATE. But depending on the size of the table and pattern you use to run the UPDATE, it could easily take less than 0.001 sec to execute

Comment: I think I understand the trick you are sharing, but wonder why the table shouldn't be locked for *both* the update and select. I'm thinking: if the table is *only* locked for one user while the update takes place then it should be released when it's done updating. Say another user requests questions at that exact moment, the new update might conflict with the select statement of the previous user, or what am I missing?